# jquery switch statement and scope issue

Tags: jquery

I have this working script (i know its incomplete):

```
function rsvpNew(selector,function_url) {
 $(selector).livequery('click',function(){
   var select = $(selector).attr('rel');
   var event_id = $(this).parents('ul.event-options').attr('rel');
   element = this;

   switch(select) {
        case "attending":
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/events/set_member/"+function_url,
        data: "event_id="+event_id,
        beforeSend:  function() {
        $("<span class='notice'>Saving...</span>").prependTo('body');
                        },
        complete: function() {


                $('span.notice').fadeOut(500);
                $(element).closest('span.rsvp-status').html("I'm Attending &ndash; <a href='javascript:;' class='remove' rel='remove'>Remove</a>");
                }


        });


             break;
```

Now the line

```
$(element).closest('span.rsvp-status').html("I'm Attending &ndash; <a href='javascript:;' class='remove' rel='remove'>Remove</a>");
```

Is working, but when I do something similar to get the parent ul of this li, it doesn't work. 
Any ideas?

Comment: what jquery are you using to get the parent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but when I do something similar to get
>   the parent ul of this li, it doesn't
>   work. Any ideas?

To get the [parent](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/parent) of something you can use a few options:

```
$('li').parent('ul'); //will return your ul
```

> Gets the direct parent of an element.

Another way is to use [closest](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/closest):

```
$('li').closest('ul'); //should also return your ul
```

> Gets a set of elements containing the
>   closest parent element that matches
>   the specified selector. Especially
>   useful for event delegation.

Comment: True but when I moved it outside of the complete function, and change element back to this, it works fine. element variable is "this" and works for the line above it.